# FavIcon issue in springMVC

Tags: spring-mvc, favicon

Our Fav icon is placed in different url and we added below link in the header jsp.
`<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" media="all" href="/siteid/_ui/responsive/theme/images/favicon.ico" />`

but still browser is searching as www.sitename.com/favicon.ico randomly mainly in google chrome. This is causing the user session out issue in springs.

Any suggestions.

Thanks,
Sreenivas A.

Answer (score 0):

I think to problem is you are missing the parent directory.

Try this

```
href="~/siteid/_ui/responsive/theme/images/favicon.ico" />
```

or

```
href="../siteid/_ui/responsive/theme/images/favicon.ico" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.I can access the favIcon from the browser with the same url.and it's a random activity(sometimes it is loading properly but in between the requests it is calling from context path) mainly from chrome browser.